# Pardons and Sealed indictment

Tags: united-states, rule-of-law, pardon

Can a presidential pardon release someone whom is charged in a sealed indictment that has not been unsealed and no charges have been filed at the time?

Answer (score 3):

The power of the President to grant pardons and reprieves is limited in few ways.

He or She cannot pardon someone for crimes committed against State law, only Federal Law. And they cannot pardon convictions following impeachment by Congress.

Beyond that, pardons have a very wide scope. They can pardon someone before they are convicted, or even before they are formally charged.  They can pardon a particular crime or (as in the case of Ford's pardon of Nixon) the president can pardon someone for any crime that might have been committed at a particular time (in Nixon's case, he was pardoned for the whole of his presidency)

So it is certainly the case that a President could pardon someone for whatever crimes might be mentioned in a sealed inditement.

Comment: Another example is when Carter pardoned draft dodgers. They didn't need to know names or even if they had been charged.